# Android selective resize elements on soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_root4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
tools:context=".Viewer4Activity" >

<com.my.mypager
    android:id="@+id/myPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false" >
</com.my.mypager>

<com.my.mypanel
    android:id="@+id/myPanelResults"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/myResults"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</com.my.mypanel>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the activity start, `myPager` show an image in fullscreen mode and the `myPanel` is hidden (`visibility="gone"`).

At this point I show the soft keyboard and the image in the `myPager` container mantains is dimension; I have setted `android:isScrollContainer="false"`

When I set the visibility of `myPanel` to visible via code, the panel is sized correctly to not be overlapped on the keyboard but also the image is resized.
How can I make the image mantains its size?

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your activity tag in the manifest?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have already tested `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but, in this case, the tag `android:isScrollContainer="true"` in `myPanel` is ignored and the keyboard overlap the panel.